# Which members are inherited from the template parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-template

If we have a class template like

```
template<class Type>
class Field {
....
};
```

Now, if I declared an object of class `Field` as

```
Field <vector> velocityField;
```

So which member functions is inherited form `vector` to my `velocityField`

Comment: What is `vector`? You mean `std::vector`?

Comment: Nothing is inherited. If you want to inherit you have to write something like `template<class Type> class Field : public Type{};` and then regular inheritance rules apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template parameters allow the compiler to perform a substitution of the generic template parameter itself, when the compiler finds a declaration of a concrete type. You are not inheriting anything.

If you use `Type` somewhere in your `Field` class, the substitution is performed accordingly and only the referenced method are looked up by the compiler.

```
template<class Type>
class Field {
  void Foo()
  {
    Type instanceOfType;
    instanceOfType.clear();
  }
  void NeverCalledMethod()
  {
     Bar(); //bar doesn't exist
  }
}; 

Field<vector> aField; // here the type Field<vector> is instantiated for the first time.
aField.Foo(); // only here the template class Foo() method is included by the compiler.
```

Under certain circumstances(eg. `Bar()`'s body has a valid syntax), the compilation won't be affected by an error in its body, if `Bar()` it's never called. 
Because `Bar()` it's never called, and the compiler can parse it but won't try to actually compile it, the above code won't produce any compiler error.

Comment: Re. the last sentence, there are some restrictions on that. For starters it can't contain syntax errors.